# Quando tento compilar da erro. Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: react, front-end, componentes, styled-components

O meu código estava funcionando até eu tentar usar Styled-Components, ele da esse erro Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. A unica coisa que fiz foi mudar os componentes, não mexi em nada do useEffect ou useState e agora tá com esse erro. O erro aponta para o setFeaturedData. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Tmdb from './Tmdb';
import Meio from './Components/Meio';
import Title from './Components/Title';

export default() => {

const [featuredData, setFeaturedData] = useState(null);
const [keyWords, setKeyWords] = useState(false);
const [featuredSimilar, setFeaturedSimilar] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {

  const loadAll = async () => {
    let list = await Tmdb.getHomeList();
    setMovieList(list);

    let originals = list.filter(i=> i.slug === 'originals');
    let randonChosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * (originals[0].items.results.length - 1));
    let chosen = originals[0].items.results[randonChosen]
    let chosenInfo = await Tmdb.getMovieInfo(chosen.id, 'tv');
    let chosenKeys = await Tmdb.getKeyWords(chosen.id);
    let chosenFeaturedSimilar = await Tmdb.getSimilar(chosen.id);
    setFeaturedData(chosenInfo);
    setKeyWords(chosenKeys);
    setFeaturedSimilar(chosenFeaturedSimilar);
    console.log(chosenFeaturedSimilar)
  }
  loadAll();
}, []);

  return (
    <div className='page'>
      {featuredData &&
        <Title item={featuredData}/>
      }
      {featuredData &&
        <Meio item={featuredData} keys={keyWords} similar={featuredSimilar}/>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Experimenta criar o componente antes de exportá-lo: `const MyComponent = () => { /* ... */ }; export default MyComponent`

Comment: Tente envolver  o componente  do styled componets entre um parenteses ao fazer renderização condicioonal. Exemplo: {featuredData &&
        (<Title item={featuredData}/>)
      }